# Send SECURE email with Outlook via VBA

Tags: vba, outlook

I have a simple code to open Microsoft Outlook and send an email with an attachment. I would like to send the email securely. Meaning, I would like to know if there is any code that would be tantamount to pressing the "Send Securely" button in outlook. Here is my code so far.....

```
    Sub EmailInvoice()
    Dim OutlookApp As Object, OutlookMessage As Object
    Dim FileName As String, EmailAddress As String

    EmailAddress = Range("ProviderEmail").Value
    FileName = "C:\Users\rblahblahblah.txt"


   Set OutlookApp = GetObject(class:="Outlook.Application") 'Handles if 
   Outlook is already open
   Err.Clear
   If OutlookApp Is Nothing Then Set OutlookApp = 
   CreateObject(class:="Outlook.Application") 'If not, open Outlook
   If Err.Number = 429 Then
   MsgBox "Outlook could not be found, aborting.", 16, "Outlook Not Found"
   Exit Sub
   End If

   'Create a new email message
   Set OutlookMessage = OutlookApp.CreateItem(0)

   'Create Outlook email with attachment
   With OutlookMessage
    .To = EmailAddress
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = "Invoice for Upload - " & Month
    .Body = "Please upload the attached file to the Vendor Portal."
    .Attachments.Add FileName
    .Display
    .Send
  End With
  End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

The code below will send it with a sensitivity enumeration but not securely (Certified Mail).  I also add my signature (Default) to the email.

```
Sub Mail_workbook_Outlook_1()
'Working in Excel 2000-2013
'This example send the last saved version of the Activeworkbook
'For Tips see: http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/winmail/Outlook/tips.htm
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim SigString As String
    Dim Signature As String
    
    For Each cell In ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Email List").Range("B1:B100")
        If cell.Value Like "?*@?*.?*" And LCase(cell.Offset(0, 1).Value) = "yes" Then
            strto = strto & cell.Value & ";"
        End If
    Next cell
    If Len(strto) > 0 Then strto = Left(strto, Len(strto) - 1)

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
    
       'Change only Mysig.htm to the name of your signature
    SigString = Environ("appdata") & "\Microsoft\Signatures\Default.htm"
    
    If Dir(SigString) <> "" Then
        Signature = GetBoiler(SigString)
    Else
        Signature = ""
    End If

    On Error Resume Next
    
    With OutMail
        .to = strto
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = ("*Confidential*: Policyholder Name Here - Policy # Here - Premium Bill")
        .HTMLBody = "Attached is the most recent premium bill in Excel." & "<br><br>" & Signature
        .Attachments.Add ActiveWorkbook.FullName
        'You can add other files also like this
        '.Attachments.Add ("C:\test.txt")
        .Importance = 2 '(0=Low, 1=Normal, 2=High)
        .Sensitivity = 3 '(0=Normal, 1=Personal, 2=Private, 3=Confidential)
        .Send   'or use .Display
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub

Function GetBoiler(ByVal sFile As String) As String
'Dick Kusleika
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim ts As Object
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.GetFile(sFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
    GetBoiler = ts.readall
    ts.Close
End Function
```